# Can my wife use my bank statement to apply for a UK standard vistor visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, yemeni-citizens

I am British citizen living abroad with a Yemeni citizen wife, I want to know if I can use my bank statement for her application and want to know whether the fact that I'm British myself would make it easier for her to get 2/5/10 year visas. Is there any advice you have for me? She doesn't work and will depositing money into her account help like £30k+?

Comment: Why do you not just state in her application that your wife has no income/savings of her own (assuming that’s the case) and that you are paying all the costs of her visit, and provide your own statements as proof of financial means? Has your wife had UK visa(s) before? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56591/how-to-get-a-10-year-uk-tourist-visa

Comment: no she hasn't been given any uk visas, we've been married 2 years now. just wondering because i heard a lot of yemenis get rejected because of the war. i dont want to apply for visas all the time which is why i want a 5/10 visa but dont want to get rejected and want to see what i could do to increase chances of her getting it.

Comment: You most probably don't want to make one single £30K deposit into her account, this will most probably be considered [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications). Also, it's usually easier to start with "smaller" visas and then ask for longer ones after she has built up a travel history rather than ask for a very long one right from the start.

Answer (score 4):

When an applicant is a non-working spouse with little or no assets of their own, it is common for their husband/wife/partner to provide the relevant financial documents in support of the application. Depositing money into your wife’s account, over and above any regular deposits you may already make, isn’t likely to help, and could even complicate matters [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Your British citizenship won’t necessarily make it any easier for her to get a long term visit visa - typically a strong reason for needing to make repeated visits plus a UK visa history is required [How to get a 10 Year UK Tourist Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56591/how-to-get-a-10-year-uk-tourist-visa). However, there is nothing to prevent her from applying for one as a first visa (personally, in such circumstances I’d consider asking for a 2 year visa initially, then build up to longer term if successful).

If you haven’t done so already, reading this guide may help https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf

Comment: If i was to apply for a 2 year visa, is it possible that they issue her a 6 month viisa instead even if i applied for a 2 year one or will they just outright reject it? so would it be better to apply for 6 month or doesnt make a difference?

Comment: @british national See the linked question - if UKVI decide she qualifies for a standard 6 month visa but not for the longer term version, they will award the 6 month visa (you don’t get a refund on the difference in fees). They will refuse the application if they decide she doesn’t qualify at all.